# Refreshing a specific div id among many divs onclick href having that same id

Tags: php, refresh, social-media-like

I want to display like count for that post the user likes, every post like href has a specific id, now if I am clicking the post having id 222. Then like count having id 222 will refresh.

```
<a href="" onclick="rate('111');">like</a> <div id="111">4</div>
<a href="" onclick="rate('222');">like</a> <div id="222">5</div>
<a href="" onclick="rate('333');">like</a> <div id="333">12</div>
```

My rate function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function rate(c) 
{   
        var c   
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'rate.php',
        data: {
                cmnt: c     
               }
         });  
          return false; 
}
</script>
```

the C variable is getting the post id

Comment: put your `rate()` function as well..

Comment: i hv given rate() function

Comment: And what is it you want us to do? What is the error?

Comment: it inserts and adds a new row to db, that is that post has one more row in db, like count increases by 1, now i have to refresh the page to show that, i want that after clicking the like link for that post that count div will refresh and display the updated like count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can update your `rate()` function as given below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function rate(c) 
    {   
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'rate.php',
            data: {cmnt: c},
            success: function(html) {
                var count = $("#"+c).html();
                var new_count = parseInt(count)+parseInt(1)
                $("#"+c).html(new_count);
             }
             });  
              return false; 
    }
    </script>
```

let me know if that helped you...

Comment: its working in some manner.. but not getting what i need.. after clicking like link its showing the text 'NAN' in the div in which like count is displayed..

Comment: @PriyaMajumder I tried the code and its working absolutely fine.. can you show me what error you are getting?